# Replace part of a long URL and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, opencart

Is there a way to redirect the URL as follows:

URL is generated based on a filtering system so it is like this

```
https://example.com/product-category-no-slash-generated-part-is-autoadded-here
```

Due to the massive product number, it is impossible for me to change all generated URL-s but I need to change, for example, only `no-slash` part to `something-else`, so redirect does this:

- **Old URL:**
  `https://example.com/product-category-no-slash-generated-part-is-autoadded-here`
- **New URL:**
  `https://example.com/product-category-something-else-generated-part-is-autoadded-here`

I hope I managed to explain the problem.

I tried to use stuff like `RewriteRule ^/no-slash/(.*)$ /something-else/$1 [L]` but I think this does not work for what I need.

Comment: To clarify, `-no-slash-` is literal text, that starts and ends with a hyphen?

Comment: MrWhite - first, thank you for answering my question. I used this "no-slash" text as an example on one end and actual info on the other, so anyone who answers can understand there is no slash since URL is generated. 

Due to business reasons, I can't disclose the actual link but let me give you another example. 

https://demo-page.com/demo-tools-for-construction-work

So word TOOLS in URL must be replaced with EQUIPMENT-AND-TOOLS. Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: So, how did you get on with my answer? Did you try it? You potentially just replace `no-slash` with the phrase you want to replace. HOWEVER, a problem with your second example is that `tools` (lowercase) also exists in the URL you are redirecting to, so would create a redirect loop. To prevent this you would need to add an exception to exclude the URL you are redirecting to. I'll update my answer. (Please address further comments related to my answer, below the answer itself, not on the question.)

Answer (score 2):

To replace `no-slash` with `something-else` in the URL-path that only consists of a single path-segment then you can do something like the following using mod-rewrite, near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Replace "no-slash" in URL-path with "something-else"
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)no-slash([\w-]+)$ /$1something-else$2 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes the URL-path can only consist of the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences contain the matched URl-path before and after the string to replace repsectively.

> I tried to use stuff like `RewriteRule ^/no-slash/(.*)$ /something-else/$1 [L]`

In this you are matching *slashes* in the URL-path - which do not occur in your example. You are also not allowing for anything before the string you want to replace (eg. `product-catgeory-`).

In a `.htaccess` context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. S, a pattern like `^/no-slash` will *never* match.

---

**UPDATE:**

> another example. `example.com/demo-tools-for-construction-work` So word `TOOLS` in URL must be replaced with `EQUIPMENT-AND-TOOLS`.

(I'm assuming this should all be lowercase.)

A problem with your second example (in comments) is that `tools` also exists in the target URL, so this would naturally result in an endless redirect loop.

To prevent this "loop" you would need to exclude the URL you are redirecting to. eg. You could exclude URLs that already contain `equipment-and-tools`.

For example:

```
# Replace "tools" in URL-path with "equipment-and-tools"
# - except if it already contains "equipment-and-tools"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !equipment-and-tools
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)tools([\w-]+)$ /$1equipment-and-tools$2 [R=302,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) negates the expression. So, in this case it is successful when `equipment-and-tools` is *not* contained in the requested URL.